# What is Landau-de Gennes Expansion?

Tags: condensed-matter, liquid-crystal

I am an undergraduate student in an introduction to condensed matter physics course and I am struggling to understand the process of Landau expansion of order parameter S as it relates to liquid crystals.

I am particularly interested in Landau expanding Maier-Saupe free energy density. But first I really just need good foundational knowledge as to what Landau expansion is. Is it as simple as a Taylor expansion about a particular order parameter?